# Dynamic Columns in

Tags: sql

I have table with the following static columns

```
ID  Sys_Date  Name prop_name1  prop_name2   prop_name3   prop_value1   prop_value2   prop_value3

10   11/2/2011Java class     method       parameter   Imanager         getOrders       orderNumber
```

I need to write SQL query  which get an input property name like “method” and go over  (prop_name1   prop_name2   prop_name3  ) and check which column
Is equal to “method”  in case I found it I need to jump 3 columns to the proper value which is “getOrders”  and get the value from there where

```
prop_name1   is mapping to prop_value1   
prop_name2   is mapping to prop_value2
prop_name3   is mapping to prop_value3
```

how can I do it with sql query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which server are you using? MySql/Oracle/Saq Server?

Comment: Don't you think it would be easier to do this by coding in programming language?

Comment: Are you allowed to redesign the database tables?

Comment: I am using oracle DB. i can;t change the table stucture.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
select name,value
from 
(
  select id, prop_name name, prop_name value
  from table
  union
  select id, prop_name2 name, prop_name2 value
  from table
  union 
  select id, prop_name3 name, prop_name3 value
  from table
)
where name = 'method'
```

...which is basically shoe-horning your data into a more easily queryable structure. You'd be better off changing the table structure, though..

Comment: You could just select * from the table and extract the results into a collection of objects.. It depends on what your use-cases are though..